# How to build a PreferredSizeWidget, not a Widget, from a FutureBuilder or async code?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I know how to build a Widget from a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), so this is my future/async function, for example:

```
Future<Null> myFuture() async
{
    // etc.
}
```

If I want to build an [AppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html) `title`, this works fine:

```
class MyStuff extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
        title: FutureBuilder(
            future: myFuture(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              // etc...
              return Text("blahblah");
            }
        ));
  }
}
```

Now, I want to build the AppBar's `bottom` which expects a [PreferredSizeWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSizeWidget-class.html), so this works, but is not async:

```
class MyStuff2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      bottom: PreferredSize(),
    );
  }
}
```

But how can I use this in a future/async way? this doesn't even compile:

```
class MyStuff3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      bottom: FutureBuilder(, // is there a FutureBuilder for PreferredSizeWidgets?
        future: myFuture(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          // etc...
          // I want to compute preferred size from async call result
          return PreferredSize(); // pseudo-code ???
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not gonna work since the FutureBuilder returns a Widget , so, what you can do is convert your stateless builder to a stateful one and create your own "PreferredSizeFutureBuilder"

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PreferredSizeFutureBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PreferredSizeFutureBuilderState createState() =>
      _PreferredSizeFutureBuilderState();
}

class _PreferredSizeFutureBuilderState
    extends State<PreferredSizeFutureBuilder> {
  bool isCompleted = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myFuture();
  }

  Future<void> myFuture() async {
    //do something

    setState(() {
      isCompleted = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
        bottom: isCompleted //we check if the future has ended
            ? PreferredSize(
                child: YourComponent(), //your component
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(12.0), //the size you want
              )
            : null); //if the future is loading we don't return anything, you can add your loading widget here
  }
}
```

Of course this means that the snapshot object is not gonna work , instead you use the isCompleted bool to check if your future is done, you can even use the ConnectionState instead of a boolean to have the "snapshot" behaviour

Comment: Thanks, it means I have to rework the whole way I'm doing things... IMHO, it looks like flutter's missing something similar to FluterBuilder for other things than just a Widget... I'll wait a bit before accepting that as an answer. PS your code misses a  ) behind the last null

Comment: Yes , it misses some things, but the beauty of Flutter is that you can see the source code and maybe reimplement or take "inspiration" from theere. My implementation can be used to create a reusableWidget if you pass the child and the future , if you want to take inspiration you can check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f6f6e86eb8b1c7bd983940222d276a9c3c1b0462/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/async.dart#L566

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap FutureBuilder into a PreferredSize-Widget.
No need to create an own FutureBuilder-Widget that implements PreferredSize.

```
    class MyStuff2 extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return AppBar(
          bottom: PreferredSize(
             child: FutureBuilder(future: _getData(), builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
               if(snapshot.data != null) {
                 return Text(snapshot.data);
                } else {
                 return Text('Loading...');
                }
            ),
             preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0),
        );
      }
    }
```